# plugin cordova-file-transfer methode download returns code error 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, mobile

I want to download an mp3 file from my website by using the plugin file transfer but the method download always sends me an error code 3. is my site must be configured to allow a third party application to download files or it is an error in my code ? 
my code is the following thank you

```
function downlaodMedia(pathName){

    var file = cordova.file.DataDirectory + pathName;
    var url= encodeURI("https://www.monsite.com/medias/" + pathName);

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(file, exestingfile, downloadfile);

    function exestingfile(fileEntry){

    }

    function downloadfile(){
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        fileTransfer.download(
            url,
            file,
            function(entry){
                navigator.notification.alert('Download Successfull', null, 
                   'Download Successfull');
            },
            function(error){
                alert("download error source " + error.source);
                alert("download error target " + error.target);
                alert("download error code " + error.code);
            },
            true,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic 
                  dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/#filetransfererror), error code 3 is a Connection error. You are sure that your app is reaching your site by HTTP?

Comment: Yes my app can reaching my site because che  can play the mp3 file who i want download in device